# Empty data object when deleting item from dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs, documentclient

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#deleteItem-property) I should get a data structure with the item as it was prior to the deletion (in case there was no error)
I do check there was no error but I get an empty object for `data`:

```
    docClient.delete(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error tring to delete item:' + err);
        callback(err, null); // error
    } else if (!data.Items || data.Items.length == 0) {
        console.info(JSON.stringify(data));
        callback(null, null); // no items
    } else  {
        console.info(JSON.stringify(data));
        callback(null, data.Items[0].ExposeStartTimestamp);
    }
});
```

Both prints empty json: `{}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order for the deleted data to appear in the response, the request should contain the attribute `ReturnValues` with value `ALL_OLD`.

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'TableName',
    Key: {
        HouseId: houseId
    },
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_OLD'
};
```

Comment: I'd hate to think what would happen if they showed that in the example...

Comment: That comment made me laugh :-)

Comment: Sagilow - have you face any issue like after deleting item in response it return null - In my case it is returning null randomly